# Finding the nth term of a numeric sequence- Newton's little formula explanation

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a contest problem book, I found a reference to Newton's little formula that may be used to find the *nth* term of a numeric sequence. Specifically, it is a formula that is based on the differences between consecutive terms that is computed at each level until the differences match.

An example application of this formula for computing the *nth* term of the series (15, 55, 123, 225, 367, 555, 795, ....) involves computing the differences as shown below:

```
1) 1st Level difference is (40, 68, 102, 142, 188, 240)
2) 2nd Level difference is (28, 34, 40, 46, 52)
3) 3rd Level difference is (6, 6, 6, 6, 6)
```

Now the nth term is  $$15{n-1\choose 0} + 40{n-1\choose 1} + 28{n-1\choose 2} + 6{n-1\choose 3}$$ where the constant multipliers are the first term of the differences at each level in addition to the first term of the sequence itself.

I was not able to find any reference to this formula or a proof of it after searching on the web. Any explanation of this method is appreciated.

Comment: LaTeX formatting will make your question much easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have formatted the nth term expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that we have a sequence:

$$a_0,a_1,...a_k$$

And we want to find the function of $n$ that defines $a_n$.

To do this we start by letting $a_{n+1}-a_n=\Delta a_n$ and we call this operation on $a_n$ the forward difference. Then given $\Delta a_n$ we can find $a_n$. Sum both sides of the equation from $n=0$ to $x-1$, and note that we have a telescoping series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{x-1} \Delta a_n=\sum_{n=0}^{x-1} (a_{n+1}-a_n)=a_{x}-a_{0}$$

Hence $a_n=a_0+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \Delta a_i$. Also $\Delta a_n=\Delta (0)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \Delta^2 a_n$...and so forth. Using this we must have if the series converges:

$$a_n=a_0+\Delta (0) \sum_{x_0=0}^{n-1} 1+\Delta \Delta (0) \sum_{x_0=0}^{n-1} \sum_{x_1=0}^{x_0-1} 1+\Delta \Delta \Delta (0) \sum_{x_0=0}^{n-1} \sum_{x_1=0}^{x_0-1} \sum_{x_2=0}^{x_1-1} 1+\cdots$$

Where $\Delta^i (0)$ denotes the first term ($n=0$) of the $i$ th difference sequence of $a_n$.

Through a combinational argument, If we take $\Delta^0 (0)=a_0$ and ${n \choose 0}=1$ we may get:

$$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \Delta^i(0) {n \choose i}$$

If it is the case you want the sequence to start with $a_1$ we need to shift this result to the right one:

$$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \Delta^i(1) {n-1 \choose i}$$

Note when you re-define $a_0$ to be $a_1$ by shifting it's index to the right one, you're re-defining $a_1-a_0=\Delta^1(0)$ to be $a_2-a_1=a_{1+1}-a_{1}=\Delta^1(1)$.

Comment: $a_1 = a_0 + \Delta a_0$,  $a_2 = a_0 + 2\Delta a_0 + \Delta^2 a_0$ and  $a_3 = a_0 + 3\Delta a_0 + 3\Delta^2 a_0 + \Delta^3 a_0$ are the first three terms. The co-efficients seem to correspond to those of the binomial expansion and it looks like the general result maybe proved using induction.

Comment: Take $D$ to be the operation mapping $f(x)$ to $f(x+1)$. And $I$ to be the operation mapping $f(x)$ to itself. $D,I$ are linear operators. So if we want to find $\Delta^n f(x)=(D-I)^n f(x)$ we may treat $(D-I)^n$ as a polynomial. Then use binomial theorem to expand and then operate on $f(x)$ with what we get for $(D-I)^n$ to get a closed form for the coefficients @erase.ego

Answer (score 4):

Starting with the second differences we have

- $28 = 28$,
- $34 = 28 + 6$,
- $40 = 28 + 6 + 6$
- $46 = 28 + 6 + 6 + 6$$

Now for the first differences we have

- $40 = 40$
- $68 = 40 + 28$
- $102 = 40 + 28 + 34 = 40 + 28 + (28 + 6)$
- $142 = 40 + 28 + 34 + 50 = 40 + 28 + (28 + 6) + (28 + 6 + 6)$

So the original sequence is

- $15 = 15$
- $55 = 15 + 40$
- $123 = 15 + 40 + 68 = 15 + 40 + [40 + 28]$
- $225 = 15 + 40 + 68 + 102 = 15 + 40 + [40 + 28] + [40 + 28 + (28 + 6)]$
- \begin{align}
  367 &= 15 + 40 + 68 + 102 + 142 \\
      &= 15 + 40 + [40 + 28] + [40 + 28 + (28 + 6)] + [40 + 28 + (28 + 6) + (28 + 6 + 6)]
  \end{align}

The patterns should be clear.  So just count how many 15's, 40's, 28's, and 6's there are in each term.

Comment: I am wondering if this argument can be generalized some how?

Comment: Well, it generalizes to any sequence given by a polynomial.  I guess you could also generalize it to a sequence where the *n*-th differences aren't constant but have some nice behavior.